# How to prove P(A ∩ B) ≤ P(A) using probability theory?

Tags: probability

How to prove P(A ∩ B) ≤ P(A) using probability theory?

I understand this when drawn on a Venn Diagram but am unsure how it translates to a formal proof.

Comment: As an instructor I would probably accept a Venn diagram as a proof. For more formality, write $A$ as a disjoint union one piece of which is $A \cap B$.

Comment: $$A \cap B \subset A \implies P(A \cap B) \leq P(A),$$ by monotonicity.

Comment: @Ethan Bolker I'm not sure a Venn diagram can be called a proof. Proofs must be formal, at least in mathematics.

Comment: @Mark True.  But when I teach I tell my students (at least at the start) that I want to see that they have convinced themselves for good reason. One sentence along with a Venn diagram would do that here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach: Every measure, hence every probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ is monotone. This means $A \subset B$ implies $\mathbb{P}(A) \le \mathbb{P}(B)$. Can you finish the idea?

Another approach would be to notice that $A = (A \cap B) \cup (A \setminus B)$ is a disjoint union. Therefore, by additivity of the measure we have
$$
\mathbb{P}(A)
= \mathbb{P}(A \cap B) + \mathbb{P}(A \setminus B).
$$
Can you finish the proof?

Comment: I think the point here is to prove monotonicity

Comment: @Jakobian This has been asked and answered on this site, see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2455330/545914).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a Venn Diagram, I presume that your sample space has equiprobable measure.

Let $U$ be the universal set.

Since $A \cap B \subseteq A$, then $\frac{n(A \cap B)}{n(U)} \leq \frac{n(A)}{n(U)}$; which inplies

$$ P(A \cap B) \leq P(A). $$